# NGINX - Proteger directorio con contraseña

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, debian, apache2

tengo un servidor con nginx+apache y quiero proteger un directorio de un virtualhost que tengo con auth_basic, como comento el servidor tiene diferentes vhosts tanto de apache como de nginx.

El dominio que quiero proteger es este **http://ejemplo1.com/api/documentation**

Para ello he hecho estos pasos

1- Crear fichero htpassword

```
location /api/documentation {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /home/user1/nginx/ejemplo1.com/.htpasswd;
}
```

Aquí tengo la duda de esta "location" ya que esta ruta puede existir en los distintos vhost de nginx.

2 - Generar htpasswd

```
htpasswd -c /home/user1/nginx/ejemplo1.com/.htpasswd
```

3 - Reinicio nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx reload

Pruebo a entrar al dominio y no me pide user y pwd.
Adjunto también la configuración del vhost.

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name test.ejemplo1.com;
root /var/www/html/ejemplo1/test/public;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}


}
```

Gracias

Comment: Agrega por lo menos un usuario al archivo, sigue comportándose igual?